# django url from a django app is giving 404 error

Tags: python, django, django-urls

demo > url.py (This is main django project url file)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),    
    path(r'^user/', include('user.urls')), 
]
```

user > url.py (this is a user app inside django project's url file)

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^/login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

now i am trying to open http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/login but its giving me 404 error.

Comment: Why exactly do you need `^` in front of those paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use a regex for [**`path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path), for regexes, you use [**`re_path(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path). But here it is not necessary: you can define this with `path(…)`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('user/', include('user.urls')),
]
```

and for `user/urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
]
```